# max(columnname) giving wrong output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

simple select max function giving wrong values. when i run the below query i am getting the max value as 100 where as the max value present in the column is 11. I have one more problem when i run this query i am getting even more worrying results all column values are going wrong. what i am doing wrong.

SELECT MAX(cast([PT_100SCALED_VAL0] as decimal)) FROM REPORT

```
SELECT t7.[timestamp], t7.[timestamp_utc], t7.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_101SCALED_VAL0],
 t7.[PT_102SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_103SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_104SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_105SCALED_VAL0],
  t7.[PT_200SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_201SCALED_VAL0], t7.[PT_300SCALED_VAL0] ,
   ( SELECT MAX([PT_100SCALED_VAL0]) FROM REPORT ) AS
    PT_100SCALED_VAL0_MAXIMUM FROM [REPORT] t7 
    Where  t7. [PT_100SCALED_VAL0]=100 
    group by t7.[timestamp],t7.[timestamp_utc],t7.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_101SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_102SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_103SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_104SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_105SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_200SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_201SCALED_VAL0],t7.[PT_300SCALED_VAL0]
```

below is my table design query

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[REPORT]    Script Date: 03/24/2016 16:24:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REPORT](
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [timestamp_utc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PT_100SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_101SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_102SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_103SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_104SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_105SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_200SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_201SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
    [PT_300SCALED_VAL0] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REPORT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [timestamp_utc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Below is my table data:

```
timestamp   timestamp_utc   PT_100SCALED_VAL0   PT_101SCALED_VAL0   PT_102SCALED_VAL0   PT_103SCALED_VAL0   PT_104SCALED_VAL0   PT_105SCALED_VAL0   PT_200SCALED_VAL0   PT_201SCALED_VAL0   PT_300SCALED_VAL0
2016-01-08 16:02:50.780 2016-01-08 10:32:50.780 11  22  33  44  55  66  0   0   0
2016-01-08 16:04:42.333 2016-01-08 10:34:42.333 11  22  33  44  55  66  0   0   0
```

Comment: What number you get from next query: `select max(PT_100SCALED_VAL0) from [dbo].[REPORT]`? If something different from 11, then your sample data is incorrect.

Comment: by running the query which you have mentioned i am getting 100 as the max value which is incorrect my data has some null values and 11 repeated several times for my pt_100scaled_val0 column

Comment: Can not be. You may have REPORT table in multiple schemas, you may have multiple databases mixed up (why your `create table` script is bound to `master` database anyway?), you may have even database corruption (not likely). Simple `max()` can't create nonexistent values. Run `select PT_100SCALED_VAL0 from [dbo].[REPORT] order by PT_100SCALED_VAL0 desc` - what values you see? Did you copy-paste my query from here or did you type it in itself? Then, about your original query, why you have space there, after t7. ? `t7. [PT_100SCALED_VAL0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `max()` subject to the `where` conditions, then use window functions instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT . . .
       MAX([PT_100SCALED_VAL0]) OVER () as PT_100SCALED_VAL0_MAXIMUM
```

Comment: still i am getting 100 instead of 11

Comment: provide some sample data to test then

Comment: can you please help me, what i am doing wrong. column datatype is float is it causing problem